# I can't get my switching power supply to turn on!

Tags: power-supply

I recently purchased a power brick ([VM-80W12](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001QX6CK2)) and I've been trying to test it with the multimeter to determine the polarity. It however registers 0 Volts continusly (yes I plugged it in) I've heard that sometimes a power supply will only switch on when it get's a load resistance on it's output and I was wondering if that was true. If so then how do I go about testing the power brick?

Comment: Connect 1 k $\Omega$ resistor to the leads and see if you get voltage drop across it. It should be enough to start the supply.

Comment: Is there any documentation as to why that is? I'd like to learn more.

Comment: @kurtnelle Description says: `VCT VM 80W12 Universal 12V AC / DC Converter Adapter ~ Input 110V or 220V / 240V AC - Output 12V DC 5.3 Amp Comes With Multiple Tips` The part you're looking at is 12 V, 5.3 A. So you need a resistor that will give some current at 12 V, but it needs to be less than 5.3 A. You also need to take a look at resistor's power rating, so that resistor doesn't burn itself. I put 1 k$\Omega$ for no particular reason. It's a common value and the dissipated power should be 0.144 W, so you can use cheap 1/4 W resistors.

Comment: @kurtnelle For further reading, take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) for the resistance value and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power) for power calculation.

Comment: @AndrejaKo: That should have been an answer, not a comment

Comment: Can someone explain how this would work, because wouldn't connecting a multimeter provide the resistive load or is it too small for the supply to output something.

Comment: After multiple resistors, and loads of frustration; I still haven't gotten the thing to turn on. Unbelievable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try plugging in a 1W 288ohm resistor across the load.

Should do the trick and turn the power supply on!

EDIT: A 270 ohm resistor would be much easier to find

Comment: 288 $\Omega$ isn't a standard resistor value, so it's going to be hard to obtain.

Comment: I've always wondered what the standard resistor values were - Is there a formula or a list somewhere?

Comment: There's a way to get the numbers. First, the scale for the resistors is logarithmic. Scales are published by Electronic Industries Association and International Electrotechnical Commission. The name of the scale starts with E and is followed by a number. The number tells us how many steps there are in the scale. The scale goes from one to 100 to 1000 and if you need smaller or larger values, you multiply and divide the scale.

Comment: You can find some more information, tips and the scales themselves [here](http://www.smpspowersupply.com/resistor/decadetable.html) and [here](http://www.logwell.com/tech/components/resistor_values.html). There are many other sites explaining this, so searching for `standard resistor values table` for example will probably give you interesting information.  Do keep in mind that the tables aren't limiting and that manufacturers can make any type of resistor they want. It's just that these are "standard" and others are proprietary